# Sorting ranges in a column

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have 4 columns filled with data from A to D. Column C is the teamwhich I have already sorted from Team 1 to 4. Now I want to further sort the sum in ascending order for each respective teams

Here's something that I think will help you visualize:

```
A1 Name  C1 Team    D1 Sum
A2 Bob   C2 Team 1  D2 32
A3 Tom   C3 Team 1  D3 79
A4 Shel  C4 Team 1  D4 15
A5 Lin   C5 Team 1  D5 58
A6 LEE   C6 Team 2  D6 61
A7 Mir   C7 Team 2  D7 13
A8 Fin   C8 Team 2  D8 46
A9 Vin   C9 Team 3  D9 92
A10 Kris C10 Team 3 D10 129
```

This is the code i used for sorting the team

```
    ovv.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ovv.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & LastRow2), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="Team 1, Team 2, Team 3, Team 4, Team 5", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
    With ovv.Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
```

How do I continue from here and sort based on the sum for each team?

Comment: [Use markdown table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to better explain your data to show what you have and what the intended outcome is. As it looks you have A1 and c1 in your data.

Comment: Also, have you tried macro recording? Seems like that give you appropriate hints.

Answer (score 1):

```
With ovv.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SetRange Range("A1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))                  'Modify if you have more columns
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1"), Order:=xlAscending           'Change the column if Team in different column
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D1"), Order:=xlAscending, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, DataOption:=xlSortColumns
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: ovv is worksheet object. Here i code as Set ovv = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).